# Excel VBA time issue

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for looking,

i have an issue with the below VBA code. Probably something simple.

If i enter the time as 23:30 it will auto change to 23:29

If i enter as 2330 it changes to 23:30 as it should.

so why when i enter 23:30 does it change to 23:29 ? it should remain as 23:30

Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xVal As String
    Set rng1 = Range("J:J")
    Set rng2 = Range("P:P")
    Set rng3 = Range("S:S")
        On Error GoTo EndMacro
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Union(rng1, rng2, rng3)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 5 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If Not .HasFormula Then
            Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ";", ":")
            Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 5)
            xVal = .Value
            Select Case Len(xVal)
                Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 00:01 AM
                    xStr = "00:0" & xVal
                Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 00:12 AM
                    xStr = "00:" & xVal
                Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 07:35 AM
                    xStr = "0" & Left(xVal, 1) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
                Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34
                    xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
                Case 5 ' e.g., 12:45 = 12:45
                    xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & Mid(xVal, 2, 1) & Right(xVal, 2)
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise 0
            End Select
            .Value = Format(TimeValue(xStr), "hh:mm")
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: when does it "change"? In the sheet when you view it or someplace in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Excel treats the time fields as fractions of a day.

For example:

- 24 hours = 1
- 12 hours = 0.5
- 6 hours = 0.25

In your case: 23h30 = 0,979166666...

But you only get the first 5 characters: `Left(Target.Value, 5)  ' "0.979"`

And pass this new value (0.979) as the current value to the cell `Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 5)`.

So on line `xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & Mid(xVal, 2, 1) & Right(xVal, 2)`, what your code is actually doing is:

`Left(0.979, 2)  ' -> "0."`

`Mid(xVal, 2, 1)  ' -> "."`

`Right(xVal, 2)  ' -> "79"`

So when you join, the result is as follows:

`"0." & "." & "79" = "0..79"`

And `"0..79"` is not a valid value for the cell. Then an error occurs and the function ends up holding the value of `0.979` ~ `23:29`.

My suggestion, do not change the value of the cell if it is already smaller than one. Because it indicates that it is already a time.

1. Delete the line: `Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 5)`
2. Assign the value of xval directly: `xVal = Left(Target.Value, 5)`
3. Alter the "case 5" condition as follow: `xStr = Format(Target.Value, "hh:mm")`

The complete code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xVal As String
    Set rng1 = Range("J:J")
    Set rng2 = Range("P:P")
    Set rng3 = Range("S:S")
    On Error GoTo EndMacro

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Union(rng1, rng2, rng3)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 5 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If Not .HasFormula Then
            Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ";", ":")
            xVal = Left(Target.Value, 5) ' CHANGED!
            Select Case Len(xVal)
                Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 00:01 AM
                    xStr = "00:0" & xVal
                Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 00:12 AM
                    xStr = "00:" & xVal
                Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 07:35 AM
                    xStr = "0" & Left(xVal, 1) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
                Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34
                    xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
                Case 5 ' e.g., 12:45 = 12:45
                    xStr = Format(Target.Value, "hh:mm") ' CHANGED!
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise 0
            End Select
            .Value = Format(TimeValue(xStr), "hh:mm") ' CHANGED!
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to do things with dates the wrong way, since the usual and recommended way to format dates is to use the `Format` statement.

However, if you want to manipulate the dates/times as strings, you need to do a few changes to your code, the 3 lines just after the test:

```
   If Not .HasFormula Then
        .Value = Replace(.Text, ";", ":") ' <-- use .Text
        .Value = Left(.Text, 5)           ' <-- 
        xVal = .Text                      ' <--
```

Or better yet, assign directly xVal:

```
   If Not .HasFormula Then
        xVal = Left(Replace(.Text, ";", ":"), 5) ' <--
```

On the other hand, what you were getting with `.Value` was an encoded date, which is usually encoded as a number, and then you were truncating the date to the leftmost 5 digits, which naturally leads to some imprecision.